# excel double conditional function

Tags: excel

I have a problem, I don't know which function do I have to use for this:

```
Column A    Discount
45
15  
48  
59  
60  
37
```

I want to use a contidional function. 
If the value in "columnA" is >30, the value in "Discount" would be "10"
If the value in "columnA" is <30, the value in "Discount" would be "5"

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's as basic as `IF` gets:

```
=IF(A2 > 30, 10, IF(A2 < 30, 5, "No discount"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the double "IF" function. =)